# Converting an adjacency matrix into a graph - matgraph

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

I should note first of all that this is my first question on *Stack Overflow*, so please forgive any errors in the presentation and format of my question!

I have the following code to convert an mx3 *.txt* file into an adjacency matrix:

```
% Converts edge list to adjacency matrix
% INPUTS: edgelist: mx3
% OUTPUTS: adjacency matrix nxn
% Note: information about nodes is lost: indices only (i1,...in) remain
% Gergana Bounova, Last updated: October 6, 2009

function adj=edgeL2adj(el)   

nodes=sort(unique([el(:,1) el(:,2)]));             % get all nodes, sorted
n=numel(nodes);                                    % number of unique nodes
adj=zeros(n);                                      % initialize adjacency matrix

for i=1:size(el,1)                                 % across all edges
  adj(find(nodes==el(i,1)),find(nodes==el(i,2)))=el(i,3);
end
```

If I have an mx3 edge list as my input, let us call it *Network* I create a matrix, *A*. I then move to create an associated graph for this adjacency matrix, using **matgraph**. But I keep encountering as error as noted shortly after below:

```
A=edgeL2adj(Network);
graph_init;
G=graph;
set_matrix(G,A);
```

Where "set_matrix.m" is the following function:

```
function set_matrix(g,A)
      % set_matrix(g,A) --- set g to be the graph specificed in the matrix A.
      % The matrix is scanned by check_matrix to be sure it is a valid adjacency
      % matrix. If it is not, an error is triggered and the graph is left
      % unchanged. 
if (~check_matrix(A))
   error('Input matrix is not a valid adjacency matrix')
end

fast_set_matrix(g,logical(A));
```

But then I get the error,

```
Error using graph/set_matrix (line 8)
Input matrix is not a valid adjacency matrix
```

I then checked the script for the "check_matrix.m" which reads as follows:

```
function ok = check_matrix(A)
% check_matrix(A) --- check if A is a valid adjacency matrix for a graph
ok = 0;
% make sure matrix is square
[nr,nc] = size(A);
if (nr ~= nc) 
    return
end
% see if the matrix is zero-one
B = (A>0); % convert to logical (so 0,1).
if (nnz(A-B)>0)
    return
end
% check if symmetric
if (nnz(A-A')>0)
    return
end
% check the diagonal
if (any(diag(A)>0)) 
    return
end
% all tests passed
ok = 1;
```

Going through each point in turn, I have found that *A* does not have a diagonal made up entirely of zeros, instead being made up of both 1's and 0's. Now, it doesn't make sense to have any value of 1 in the main diagonal for and adjacency matrix, as there does not exist any walk of length one from a node to itself again; the shortest closed walk in an undirected network from a node to itself is 2.

Does anybody have any ideas as to why the function "adj=edgeL2adj(el).m" has not worked here in converting my *.txt* file to a valid adjacency matrix? I had thought to try and just "zero" the main diagonal, but don't know if this would alter the matrix any more than it already has been, so rendering all subsequent analysis and work wrong.

Cheers!

**EDIT:** Here are the first ten rows from the .txt file:

```
1   1   1
4   1   1
2530    1   1
4   2   1
6   2   1
571 2   1
2275    3   1
1   4   1
2   4   1
6   4   1
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem with the sample edge lists that I generated. Do you have a (small) sample that causes `edgeL2adj` to give you an invalid adjacency matrix?

Comment: Here are the first ten rows from the .txt file of the edge lists:

1 1 1
4 1 1
2530 1 1
4 2 1
6 2 1
571 2 1
2275 3 1
1 4 1
2 4 1
6 4 1

Comment: `1 1 1` looks like it shouldn't be there, right? Please edit your question and add the edge list with some formatting so we can see the columns.

Comment: 1 1 1 is the first row of the .txt file though. I don't know if the problem is in the formatting of the .txt file, because when I load it into matlab the column entries "overlap" one another, as shown in the edited version of the question.

Comment: Well, if you're reading `1 1 1` as an edge, then it's definitely going to be on the diagonal. You should probably search your input file for more edges where `el(k,1) == el(k,2)`.